# return the rows by family with sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, duplicates

This is my first question in stackoverflow so be nice to me :)

i have a table which has a column family, when i make a query (with a where statment) i want to show the results as a group of rows with the same family

for example the table is shop:

```
+----+--------+-------+
| id | family | money |
+----+--------+-------+
|  1 |      1 |   100 |
|  2 |      1 |    70 |
|  3 |      2 |    10 |
|  4 |      2 |    20 |
|  5 |      3 |    50 |
+----+--------+-------+
```

So i want when executing a query like this :

```
SELECT * FROM shop where money=100 --(adding to the query of course what's needed)
```

it will select these two :

```
+-----+----------+---------+
| id  |  family  |  money  |
+-----+----------+---------+
| 1   |       1  |    100  |
| 2   |       1  |     70  |
+-----+----------+---------+
```

Comment: You want all rows for a family where any 1 row for that family = 100? -seems a bit odd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `in` or `exists`:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM shop 
WHERE s.family IN (SELECT s2.family FROM shop s2 WHERE s2.money = 100);
```

Comment: Would an `ORDER BY family` grouping them together  be useful as well.

Comment: Thank you very much it did help me and it was fast too!!  :) :)

Comment: i had an unexpected result when using (in the last part) "WHERE (e2.money like "%text%")" indeed i had the "text" showing but in addition other results as well that doesn't have "text" in them at all, please any Help would be appreciated!

Comment: @jason9 . . . In this question, `money` is reasonable assumed to be a number.  If you have another question regarding strings, then please ask another question, with appropriate standard data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Correlated Subquery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/correlated-subqueries.html) with [`Exists()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html):

```
SELECT
  t1.*
FROM shop t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM shop t2
              WHERE t2.family = t1.family AND 
                    t2.money = 100)
```